# How Can I Run a Cloud-Init User data YAML File

Tags: ubuntu, cloud-init

I'm having this YAML file that I would like to run via cloud-init and I'm running into errors. Here is what I did:

1. Created a folder called /myfolder-config on the root file system
2. Copied the YAML file to this location:

> ```
>  #cloud-config
> ssh_pwauth: false
>
> groups:
>   - openelectrons_k3s: [openelectrons]
>
> users:
>   - name: openelectrons
>     gecos: openelectrons
>     sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
>     groups: sudo
>     ssh_import_id: None
>     lock_passwd: true
>     shell: /bin/bash
>     ssh_authorized_keys:
>       - <ssh-pub-key>
>
> hostname: openelectrons-k3s-<num>
> ```

I face these error:

```
usage: /usr/bin/cloud-init [-h] [--version] [--file FILES] [--debug] [--force] {init,modules,single,query,dhclient-hook,features,analyze,devel,collect-logs,clean,status,schema} ...
/usr/bin/cloud-init: error: unrecognized arguments: /myfolder-config/
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I gave up on using cloud-init and started ti use Ansible and it works like a charm! I regret that I had to waste time on this topic with no result from anywhere or anyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

It looks like you tried to run `cloud-init /myfolder-config/`, which is not how cloud-init is intended to be used.

For help getting started with cloud-init, consider starting with a [tutorial](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/index.html).